Blank Values to 0 in TIBCO Spotfire
I do have column name "Grade" and there are some rows have blank values. I want to replace all blank values to 0 but I still can't figure it out. Since my data came from SQL Management Studio so I can't just do the 'Replace Values'
I am trying this function but still not working
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN [Grade] IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE
        [Grade]
END


There is a function in the list of expressions called SN() which replaces nulls with a chosen value.
You can add it as a replace column transformation in the data canvas, so you do not create a new column.
